# non-static method hasNextLine() cannot be referenced from a static context without having a static keyword

Tags: java

The following code is to check whether the given word or string is pangram or not. But I am facing this error: `non-static method hasNextLine() cannot be referenced from a static context`
I used this site for solving https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler can anyone help me to solve this please?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class PangramChecker {
  public  void main(String[] args)
  {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      if(Scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String words = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(check(words));
                
        }
  }
  public  boolean check(String sentence){
    sentence= sentence.replace(" ","");
    String temp="";
    
    for(int c:sentence.toCharArray())
      if((c>64 &&c<91)||(c>96 && c<123))
        temp+=(""+(char)c);
    sentence = temp;
    
    if(sentence.length()<26)
      return false;
    
    else
      {
      sentence= sentence.toLowerCase();
      String output="";
      for(char c:sentence.toCharArray())
        output=presenceChecker(output,c);
        System.out.println("The output is:"+output);
      if(output.length()==26)
        return true;
      else 
        return false;
        
    }  
    
  }
  public  String presenceChecker(String str,char c)
    {
    boolean present=false;
    for(char k:str.toCharArray())
      {
      if(k==c)
        present=true;
      }
    if(present)
      str+=(""+c);
    return str;
  }
}
```

Comment: Obviously, you are making a minor error. You should be calling `input.hasNextLine()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Line 5:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Line 6:

```
if(Scanner.hasNextLine())
```

Your `Scanner` variable is called `input`, not `Scanner`. You're trying to call the method on the class, but it is not static, so only *instances* of that class have the method.